# How to get index of an array in promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

This is my simple code which just adds a question in a database and then get an id as the result and then tries to add `questionId` in all `answer.questionId`

```
var size = questions.length;

for(var i=0; i<size; i++){                  
    $http.post(url + "questions", questions[i]).success(function(result){
        questions[i].answers = questions[i].answers.map(function(answer){
            return answer.questionId = result;
        });
    });
}
```

But promise calls in the end of the loop, therefore, question[i] - undefined since `i = size`;

How to solve the problem ?

Comment: Java != JavaScript. (Not even a little bit.)

Comment: I know, I just made a mistake (it happens to everyone).
Thanks for the duplicate link

Comment: `it happens to everyone` - mainly java "programmers" :p

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Java is 40% JavaScript

Comment: @JaromandaX: Surely it's the other way around. ;-)